# create folder in remote server using bitbucket branch name via pipeline

Tags: linux, git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am developing a Laravel project and I want to have CI with it. I am using bitbucket pipelines to do this. and I am using a ubuntu VPS.I would like to have separate folders for release-branchname.

for example, if I create a branch `release-1.0.0` in bitbucket, and when i am trying to deploy it should create a folder in my remote server `projectname/releases/release-1.0.0`. I tried many ways but I was not successful.

here is my pipeline script

```
release-*:
      - step:
          name: Preparing pipeline for release
          script:
            - echo 'Preparing pipeline for releases'

      - step:
          name: Deploing release branches
          trigger: manual
          deployment: test
          script:
            - cat ./deploy.sh | ssh root@X.X.X.X
```

and here is my `deploy.sh`

```
echo 'Deployment started'
cd /home/core-cms/project-root
mkdir /home/core-cms/$BITBUCKET_BRANCH
git stash
git pull origin master
composer install
echo 'Deploy finished'
exit;
```

if I could pass $BITBUCKET_BRANCH variable into this deploy.sh, it would work perfectly I guess.

maybe I am totally wrong and there is another way to accomplish this. if so can anyone guide me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a git repo initialized at `/home/core-cms/project-root`? What are you expecting to happen when you `git stash` and `git pull origin master`?

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica yes i have

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things that you are attempting to do:

1. Get name of the branch from the commit and pass it to the next step

```
default:
    - step:
        deployment: test
        script:
          - ssh user@host "bash -s" -- < ./deploy.sh $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
```

2. Get the branch name in your scrip and do the rest

```
BITBUCKET_BRANCH=${1}
echo 'Deployment started'
cd /home/core-cms/
git clone -b $BITBUCKET_BRANCH user@repository.com
composer install
echo 'Deploy finished'
exit;
```

Here is what I have done in the code in steps:

- The $BITBUCKET_BRANCH is an standard Bitbucket variable. Be aware that this var is not available using custom or tag trigers.
- In the pipeline code call the script on local machine pass the branch    name to it and execute it on ssh server. The code `ssh user@host "bash -s" -- <` will run the rest of the code as if it is running it as a local code. Adding `--` will stop the remote bash to take rest of the arguments for itself.
- By adding the `$BITBUCKET_BRANCH` after the script file name, we pass it to the script.
- In the script we get the input argument using `$1` and assign it to    `$BITBUCKET_BRANCH` variable.
- The code will clone the code in the sub-directory. Here you might
  need some changes to avoid git conflicts.

---

P.S. Just to mention, I haven't test the code. It might have some misspellings. However, the solution is there. You might be able to alter it to what you'd like to do.